# Remove 'and' from biblatex' text citations

Tags: biblatex, citing

Since version 2.7, `biblatex` adds the word `and` before the last citation in a string of text citations. That's pretty nice, but this catch-all behavior is not always appropriate, as in the example below.

The question is, how can I suppress the addition of `and` in cases where I know it would not be appropriate?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1972,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Peace on earth",
    YEAR = "1972",
    LOCATION = "London",
    PUBLISHER = "Music Press"}
@BOOK{lennon1974,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "More peace on earth",
    YEAR = "1974",
    LOCATION = "London",
    PUBLISHER = "Music Press"}
@BOOK{mccartney1975,
    AUTHOR = "Paul McCartney",
    TITLE = "Let's talk about music instead",
    YEAR = "1975",
    LOCATION = "London",
    PUBLISHER = "Music Press"}
@UNPUBLISHED{harrisonms,
    AUTHOR = "George Harrison",
    TITLE = "My dirty secrets about the Beatles"}
@BOOK{starr1985,
    AUTHOR = "Richard Starkey",
    TITLE = "My life",
    YEAR = "1985",
    LOCATION = "London",
    PUBLISHER = "Music Press"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
You can find a lot of interesting material on the Beatles,
such as \textcites{lennon1972}{lennon1974}{mccartney1975},
the never published manuscript by \citeauthor{harrisonms},
and finally Ringo Starr's autobiography \parencite{starr1985}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `\AtNextCite{\renewcommand*{\textcitedelim}{\addcomma\space}}` before the respective citation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1972,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Peace on earth",
    YEAR = "1972",
    LOCATION = "London",
    PUBLISHER = "Music Press"}
@BOOK{lennon1974,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "More peace on earth",
    YEAR = "1974",
    LOCATION = "London",
    PUBLISHER = "Music Press"}
@BOOK{mccartney1975,
    AUTHOR = "Paul McCartney",
    TITLE = "Let's talk about music instead",
    YEAR = "1975",
    LOCATION = "London",
    PUBLISHER = "Music Press"}
@UNPUBLISHED{harrisonms,
    AUTHOR = "George Harrison",
    TITLE = "My dirty secrets about the Beatles"}
@BOOK{starr1985,
    AUTHOR = "Richard Starkey",
    TITLE = "My life",
    YEAR = "1985",
    LOCATION = "London",
    PUBLISHER = "Music Press"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
You can find a lot of interesting material on the Beatles,
such as \AtNextCite{\renewcommand*{\textcitedelim}{\addcomma\space}}%
\textcites{lennon1972}{lennon1974}{mccartney1975},
the never published manuscript by \citeauthor{harrisonms},
and finally Ringo Starr's autobiography \parencite{starr1985}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to retype it every time I need it? I.e. something like ``\removeand`` = ``\AtNextCite{\renewcommand*{\textcitedelim}{\addcomma\space}}``?

Comment: @Sverre `\newcommand*{\removeand}{\AtNextCite{\renewcommand*{\textcitedelim}{\addcomma\space}}}`

Comment: We could consider adding a starred variant that prints `\multicitedelim` instead of `\textcitedelim`. But use of multiple `\textcite` commands is probably the most straightforward for composition: "such as `\textcite{lennon1972}`, `\textcite{lennon1974}`, `\textcite{mccartney1975}`, the never..."